# batch file code to remove comma from .csv file

Tags: csv, batch-file, trim, space

I need a batch file code to remove comma from the first column of my `.csv` file and also remove spacing from the first row of the `.csv` file.

Thanks for the help

i have following data into my `.csv` file :

```
Column 1          Column 2
"LAMAR,JOY"       indian
"Samar,sinha"     American
```

i have to replace , with - only into the column 1.

how can i do this ??

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "col1="
(
 FOR /f "delims=" %%c IN (q29471006.txt) DO (
  FOR /f "tokens=1delims= " %%a IN ("%%c") DO (
   IF DEFINED col1 (
    SET "col1=%%a"
    SET "col1=!col1:,=-!"
    SET "line=%%c"
    SET "line=!line:* =!"
    ECHO(!col1! !line!

   ) ELSE (
    SET "col1=%%c"
    SET "col1=!col1: =!"
    ECHO(!col1!
   )
  )
 )
)>u:\newfile.txt
```

Since you don't show what you expect as output, we're left to guess.

I used a file named `q29471006.txt` containing your data for my testing.

The output of this routine (in `u:\newfile.txt`) is

```
Column1Column2
"LAMAR-JOY"       indian
"Samar-sinha"     American
```

WHich makes little sense to me, but this has the spaes removed from the first row and the remainder has ommas replaced by `-` in the first column.

The file is read into `%%c`. since `col1` is initilised to *empty*, then `col1` is not defined for the first row, so the entire line is assigned to `col1`, the spaces remmoved and the result `echo`ed.

Since `col1` is now defined, the remaining lines are processed after the line has been tokenised on the space separating the columns (it's fixed-column format, not csv.) `%%a` acquires the first column and is assigned to `col1` which then has each `,` replaced by `-`. The entire line from `%%c` is assigned to `line` and the characters up to and including the first space are then deleted from `line` The required output is thus the content of `col1` + the space which was deleted + the remainder of the line in `line`.